# Creating binary tree and passing node as pass by reference

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to create a binary tree and i am new to data structure.
What i have to do is:

(1) Take the size of tree (total number of nodes) at terminal.

(2) Then up to size read nodes from the user at terminal

(3) Then create Binary search tree.

Note: I have to pass the node by reference only` in the function call(No other options).

It compiles without error but i guess there is any logical problem.**It gives segmentation fault  when i try to insert second node in for loop (for first it works fine)  but compile without errors** .I am not able to predict it's due to which line of code? 
When I do:

```
How many  nodes are to be inserted ?
5
enter the nodes 
1 //I am not able to add more nodes
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer in any language c/c++ or even algorithm are welcome.

My code to do so is :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h> 
#include <string.h>


struct node 
{
    int freq;
    struct node * left, * right;
};
typedef struct node node;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Function definitions //////////////////////////////////////////////////
insert_first_node(int data, node * * Node) 
{
  node * temp1 ;
  temp1 =  Node;
  temp1= (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
  temp1 -> freq = data;
  temp1 -> left = NULL;
  temp1 -> right = NULL; 
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
insert_beginning(int data, node * * Node) 
{
    root = * Node;
root = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));;
    if (root ==NULL) 
    {
        insert_first_node(data, & root);
    }
    if (data <= root -> freq) 
    {
        insert_beginning(data, & root -> left);
    } else 
    {
        insert_beginning(data, & root -> right);
    } 
    *Node = root;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
main() 
{
    int i, size, data;
    node * head;
    head = NULL;

    printf("How many  nodes are to be inserted ?\n");
    scanf("%d", & size);
    for (i = 1; i <= size; i++) 
    {
        printf("enter the nodes \n");
        scanf("%d", & data);
        insert_beginning(data, & head);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write it like this (although I wouldn't necessarily use recursion, but maybe you are supposed to...):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node 
{
    int freq;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
} Node;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function definitions                                  //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int insert_leaf_node(int freq, Node **parent_ptr) 
{
  Node *node;

  if ((node = malloc(sizeof *node)) == NULL)
      return -1;

  node->freq = freq;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL; 
  *parent_ptr = node;
  return 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int insert_node(int freq, Node **parent_ptr) 
{
    Node *node = *parent_ptr;

    if (node == NULL) {
        return insert_leaf_node(freq, parent_ptr);
    }
    else if (freq <= node->freq) {
        return insert_node(freq, &node->left);
    }
    else {
        return insert_node(freq, &node->right);
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() 
{
    int i, size, freq;
    Node *root = NULL;

    printf("How many  nodes are to be inserted ?\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("enter the freq of node %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &freq);
        insert_node(freq, &root);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here's how I would write `insert_node` without recursion:

```
int insert_node(int freq, Node **parent_ptr)
{
    Node *node;

    while ((node = *parent_ptr) != NULL) {
      parent_ptr = (freq <= node->freq) ? &node->left : &node->right;
    }

    return insert_leaf_node(freq, parent_ptr);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the working code. there are number of question even after working code : (1) Why do you return int in both the function (even we are doing pass by reference, it's useless i think)(2) Why return insert_leaf_node(freq, root);? WHY not return insert_leaf_node(freq, &node);(3) Why we don't we create memory dynamically for leftchild and rightchild addition of root using malloc(like,node = malloc(sizeof *node))because here also we add a node.

Comment: To explain more my third point: What i have in my mind is :First we got root node at the terminal, We allocated memory for it using malloc() and the second element is if greater will go in right(Why don't we again need to create memory for that node as well ?(using malloc)?? But you don't do this here, You just do Node *node for that), You just create memory dynamically for root node only when it is the case of NULL. As i was trying to do in my insert_beginning()function.I try to allocate memory dynamically for left and right child as well using root = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));.

Comment: The `int` return is `0` for success and `-1` for failure.  We could have returned a non-`NULL` pointer to the newly inserted `Node` on success, and a `NULL` pointer on failure.

Comment: Calling `insert_leaf_node(freq, &node)` will update the local variable `node` to point to the new `Node`; however, we want to update the `root` pointer in `main` (if the tree is empty), or either the `left` or `right` pointer in the parent `Node`.

Comment: Calling `insert_leaf_node` always creates a new `Node` with `malloc`, and hooks it to the location pointed to by the `root` argument.  The name `root` is a misnomer; it is only really the root of the tree if the tree is empty; otherwise, it is a pointer to the `left` or `right` pointer in the parent `Node`.

Comment: Maybe if you single-step through the code with a debugger, you will see how each `Node` is allocated with `malloc` in the call to `insert_leaf_node`.  The root node is no different than any other node in that respect; the only difference is in where we stash the pointer to the new node.

Comment: but  insert_leaf_node() is called only once in your code when if(node =NULL) condition executed(on the very first execution of insert_beginnign function). After that only recursive calls to insert_beginning is done.So how memeory allocated for them dynamically?it is just allocated first time only.

Comment: `insert_node` calls itself recursively as it walks down the tree.  Eventually, it will decide to walk down a `left` or `right` link that is `NULL`.  The last call to `insert_node` will see that it has been passed a pointer to a NULL pointer, and will call `insert_leaf_node` which will create a new node and connect it to the `left` or `right` pointer in the parent node.  The `if(node == NULL)` doesn't just handle the case of the root node being `NULL`, it handles the case of a body node with a `NULL` pointer in its `left` or `right` field as well.

Comment: I changed the name of the `root` parameter to `parent_ptr` to indicate that it is not necessarily a pointer to the root pointer, but a pointer to the place where we should store the pointer to the new `Node`.  If the tree is empty, we want to store the pointer to the new `Node` in the `root` variable in `main`.  If the tree is non-empty, then we will want to store the pointer to the new `Node` in the `left` or `right` field of the parent `Node`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48822/discussion-between-user234839-and-pat)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting segmentation fault starting from first input only. Let me clear the reason for that.
In `insert_beginning` function, first line is `root = * Node;`. Here `*Node` is `NULL` already. So `root` would have `NULL` value also. You expected that root also points to same address as `*Node` but this is not the case as `*Node` is pointing to nothing, so `root` and `*Node` are still unrelated. Now you have allocated the memory to `root` in previous line, but now you have assigned `NULL` to `root`. So previous assigned address to `root` is lost. So that is the leak memory, Dalibor is talking about.
Lets go ahead.
Now `root==NULL` is checked, which is true, so `insert_first_node` is called. There is `temp1=Node`, which is syntactically wrong. I think you intended `temp1 = *Node`. But still that is wrong as `*Node` is `NULL`, so would be `temp1`. Now you are assigning value to `NULL` object. So next line gives segmentation fault.

The working code can be

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h> 
#include <string.h>


struct node 
{
    int freq;
    struct node * left, * right;
};
typedef struct node node;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Function definitions //////////////////////////////////////////////////
void insert_first_node(int data, node * * Node,int direction) 
{
    node * temp1 = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp1 -> freq = data;
    temp1 -> left = NULL;
    temp1 -> right = NULL; 
    if(*Node == NULL)
        *Node = temp1;
    else if(direction == 1)
        (*Node)->right = temp1;
    else
        (*Node)->left = temp1;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void insert_beginning(int data, node * * Node) 
{
    node *root;
    root = * Node;
    if (root == NULL) 
    {
        insert_first_node(data,Node,0);
        return;
    }
    if (data <= root -> freq) 
    {
        if(root->left == NULL)
            insert_first_node(data,&root,0);
        else
            insert_beginning(data,&root->left);
    } else 
    {
        if(root->right == NULL)
            insert_first_node(data,&root,1);
        else
            insert_beginning(data,&root->right);
    } 
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
main() 
{
    int i, size, data;
    node * head;
    head = NULL;

    printf("How many  nodes are to be inserted ?\n");
    scanf("%d", & size);
    for (i = 1; i <= size; i++) 
    {
        printf("enter the nodes \n");
        scanf("%d", & data);
        insert_beginning(data, & head);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Shaswant thanks for the answer, But i have one doubt:Suppose first we got root node at the terminal, We allocated memory for it using malloc() and the second element is if greater will go in right(Why don't we again need to create memory for that node as well ?(using malloc)?? But you don't do this here, You just do Node *node for that), You just create memory dynamically for root node only when it is the case of NULL. As i was trying to do in my insert_beginning()function.I try to allocate memory dynamically for left and right child as well using root = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));.

Comment: I am allocating memory for that also. I am calling insert_beginning recursively till root->next is not NULL. So when root->next is NULL, I am calling insert_first_node. That function is allocating memory for next input node. But the memory allocated by the function should should be appended to original linked list, so I am returning the address of newly allocated memory and linking that to previous one.

Comment: Thanks, But if you pass the Node by reference to the function  insert_first_node() then also Will you need to return the address of newly allocated memory ? we can simply assign *Node=temp1(I suppose if you passed "Node" in inset_first_node() as second parameter by reference). Am I Right ? (Actually i have to do without returning anything)

Comment: I have updated the code according to your requirements.

Comment: The problem is here. When you are assigning memory for first input. *Node is null and you need to allocate memory to *Node itself but when assigning memory for second or subsequent inputs, the memory should be linked to *Node->right.

Comment: Also you need to send a new parameter telling whether new memory should be allocated to *node->left or *node->right. I have done only *node->right. You can change that

Comment: @What we will do in case of left child, because you have just else
        (*Node)->right = temp1; (for right only)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48816/discussion-between-user234839-and-shashwat-kumar)

Comment: @Shashwant, Thanks for the working code but there are few thing extra in your code (even it is working) .Actually there is no need to call the insert_first_node() three times, Just one call in if(root=NULL) condition is enough, int the other two condition we just need to give &root->left/right and there is no need of extra if else conditions that you have kept.

Answer (score 0):

It seg-faults during the insertion of your first node. If it was during the second insert, you would see the message "enter the nodes" twice.

Now to the reason. In the function insert_beginning, the first if statement does not compare root to NULL, but sets it to NULL. Since NULL is treated as false, the code inside the if is not evaluated and the execution moves to the second if statement. In it, you're trying to access freq field of root, which is set to NULL from the first if statement. So you are trying to dereference NULL pointer, which leads to the seg-fault.

Comment: thanks ,could you please give a little piece of code to make as reference (because that will be more explained, I want to know how the experience programmers write the same thing with pass by reference) ? Thanks

Comment: I am still not able to understand what you said (I have made some changes in code but problem still persists).(How can root be set to NULL in if condition parameter? and How i am leaking memory ?) Could you please give me the implementation of what you just said ?

Comment: in the first if statement, it should be if( root == NULL ), not if (root = NULL) (see the double equals?). As for the memory leaking, it was present in the code you posted the previous version of your question.

Comment: I just done if(root==NULL) and it still persists the same error.Code edited again.